# Enviar información de un componente a otro react

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, express

Tengo el siguiente componente que muestra canciones médiate la api de spotify, y efectivamente se muestran correctamente, en la constante list of songs hago el map para mostrar cada canción y algo de su información, ahora cuando se hace click en la etiqueta Link quiero enviar la información completa de esa cancion a la que le di click a otro componente para mostrar todo, he intentado con props, pero el componente a donde quiero enviar la info esta ruteado en app, y no se como podría colocarle la propiedad.

Gracias por la ayuda

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
    import Authenticate from '../utils/Authenticate'
    import axios from 'axios'
    import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
    
    
    export default function SearchingBar() {
        const [keyWord, getValue] = useState(''); 
    
        const token = Authenticate();
         //la funcion obtiene el valor del input
        const getInputValue = (e) => {
            getValue(e.target.value);
        }
    
        const [answear, data] = useState([])
    
    
        const onSubmit = async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            if(keyWord){
                const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/home/${keyWord}/${token}`);
                data(res.data)
            }else{
                alert("datos incorrectos");
            }
        }
    
        console.log(answear);
    
        const renderListOfSongs = () => {
            if(answear.length > 0){
                return listOfSongs;
            }else{
                return error;
            }
        }
    
    
    const listOfSongs = (
        
        <div className= "d-flex flex-wrap justify-content-between mt-5">
        {
            answear.map(item => {
                return(
                    <div key={item.name} className="cardSongs card mb-4 position-relative">
                        <h6 className="position-absolute bg-primary p-2 text-white popularity">Popularity {item.popularity}</h6>
                        <Link to="/singleSong" className="text-decoration-none">
                            <div>
                                <img src={item.album.images[0].url} className="card-img-top" alt="..."></img>
                                <div className="card-body">
                                    <h5 className="card-title mb-0 d-flex overflow-hidden title">{item.name}</h5>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Link>
                    </div>
                )
            })
        }
    </div>
    )
    
    const error = (
        <div class="alert alert-primary mt-5 rounded-0" role="alert">
            Todavia no has buscado nada o la busqueda no arroja resultados prueba con otras palabras
        </div>
    )
    
        return (
            <div className="container mt-5">
                {keyWord}
                <form className="d-flex" onSubmit={onSubmit}>
                    <input type="text"
                        id="inputPassword5"
                        className="form-control border-end-0 rounded-0"
                        //El input inicia con valor 0
                        value={keyWord}
                        onChange={getInputValue}>
                    </input>
                    <button type='submit' className="btn btn-info rounded-0 pl-5 pr-5">
                        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="16" height="16" fill="currentColor" className="bi bi-search" viewBox="0 0 16 16">
                        <path d="M11.742 10.344a6.5 6.5 0 1 0-1.397 1.398h-.001c.03.04.062.078.098.115l3.85 3.85a1 1 0 0 0 1.415-1.414l-3.85-3.85a1.007 1.007 0 0 0-.115-.1zM12 6.5a5.5 5.5 0 1 1-11 0 5.5 5.5 0 0 1 11 0z"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </form>
                {renderListOfSongs()}     
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Si el componente está enrutado en App usa `Context`. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Forward Props (Lo que te recomiendo)

---

Quizá esta solución te pueda servir. Simplemente consiste en crear el evento en el componente padre, tal que lo puedas referenciar en el componente hijo. El problema de esto, es que puede que termines pasando un prop a muchos componentes que no les interesa. Sin embargo, si el nivel de profundidad del componente no supera los 3 niveles, puedes ir por esta opción.

**Este sería el flujo**

Si tienes:

**(App)** -> (SongComponent) : Usa éste método

Si tienes:

**(App)** -> (OtroComp) -> (OtroComp) -> (SongComponent) : Usa éste método

Si el arbol se complica más que estos casos que te presenté, tal vez deberías usar una herramienta de control de estado local en tu app. (Redux, MobX, etc...)

### Si optas por esta solución, tal vez necesites algo como esto:

```
// Componente Padre
function App() {
  const [songDetails, setSongDetails] = useState(null)

  // Aquí puedes setear o el ID de la canción o todo el objeto 
  const handleSelectSong = (songInformation) => {
    setSongDetails(songInformation)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SongComponent onSelectSong={handleSelectSong} />
    </div>
  );
}

function SongComponent(props) {
   const { onSelectSong } = props  

  // Estoy suponiendo que en este componente guardas la lista de canciones.
  const [songList, setSongList] = useState()

  
  // Supongo tambien que seleccionas la canción dependiendo de su id o posición en 
  // el array, eso te lo dejo a tí.

  const handleSelectSong = () => {
    // Suponiendo que la escoges por ID:
    onSelectSong(songList[songId]) // Con esto seleccionas la canción
  }
  // Acá puedes renderizar la lista de canciones y mandar el ID o el index en el 
  // que se encuentra para posteriormente usarlo en la función de arriba
  return (
  
    <div>
     {songList.map(({name, id}) => {
       return <li key={id} onClick={() => handleSelectSong(id)}>{name}</li>
     })}
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

## React Context

---

> Context provee una forma de pasar datos a través del árbol de componentes sin tener que pasar props manualmente en cada nivel.

Si así lo deseas, puedes crear un contexto el cual puedes consumir perfectamente. El problema de esto es que cada componente que esté escuchando el context va ser re-renderizado cada vez que asignes la información de la canción.

Esta solución puede ser bastante sencilla, sin embargo fue diseñada para información que no esté cambiando constantemente. Si la asignación de detalles de la canción es algo que sucede con frecuencia, pues no te recomiendo esta solución.